# "it is sticks out here"

Tags: meaning-in-context

This excerpt belongs to the short story "Feathers", contained in 'Cathedral' by Raymond Carver.

> We turned right like the map said and drove exactly three and
> three-tenths miles. On the left side of the road, I saw a field of
> corn, a mailbox, and a long, graveled driveway. At the end of the
> driveway, back in some trees, stood a house with a front porch. There
> was a chimey on the houses. But it was summer, so, of course, no smoke
> rose frome the chimney. But I thought it was a pretty picture, and I
> said so to Fran.
> **“It’s the sticks out here,”** she said.

**“It’s the sticks out here”**
I wonder if this response (nuance) means it's indeed attract attention or it's just country house (sarcastic remarks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your title you have missed the word "the".  That is critical.

"[The sticks](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_sticks)" is an idiom meaning "a remote rural location. It usually has a negative connotation.  Fran doesn't like the area because it is too far from the city.